# Minimum size of rendered object using GL_LINES in iOS Open GL ES

Tags: ios, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

I have just completed the first version of my iOS app, [Corebox](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/corebox/id503591554), and am now working on some new features.

One of the new features is a "small" tweak to the OpenGL rendering to force some objects to never be drawn smaller than a minimum size.  All of the objects needing this treatment are simple 2 point lines drawn with GL_LINES.

This annotated screenshot explains what I'm after.  Ignore the grey lines, the only objects I'm interested in altering are the yellow wider lines.

[image: Corebox OpenGL scene]

I have googled this extensively and it seems what I need to do is alter the geometry of the lines using a vertex shader.  I'm quite new to GLSL and most shader examples I can find deal with applying lighting and other effects, eg: [GLSL Heroku Editor](http://glsl.heroku.com) and [KicksJS shader editor](http://www.kickjs.org/example/shader_editor/shader_editor.html).

My current vertex shader is extremely basic:

```
// GL_LINES vertex shader
uniform mat4 Projection;
uniform mat4 Modelview;

attribute vec4 Position;
attribute vec4 SourceColor;

varying vec4 DestinationColor;

void main(void) {
    DestinationColor = SourceColor;
    gl_Position = Projection * Modelview * Position;
}
```

As is my fragment shader:

```
// GL_LINES fragment shader
varying lowp vec4 DestinationColor;

void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor = DestinationColor;
}
```

My guess as to what is required:

- Determine the distance between the viewer (camera position) and the object
- Determine how big the object is on the screen, based on its size and distance from camera
- If the object will be too small then adjust its vertices such that it becomes large enough to easily see on the screen.

Caveats and other notes:

1. But if you zoom out won't this cause the model to be just a blob of orange on the screen?  Yes, this is exactly the effect I'm after.

**Edit: Here is the final working version implementing suggestions by mifortin**

```
uniform mat4 Projection;
uniform mat4 Modelview;
uniform float MinimumHeight;

attribute vec4 Position;
attribute vec4 ObjectCenter;
attribute vec4 SourceColor;

varying vec4 DestinationColor;

void main(void) {
    // screen-space position of this vertex
    vec4 screenPosition = Projection * Modelview * Position;
    // screen-space mid-point of the object this vertex belongs to
    vec4 screenObjectCenter   = Projection * Modelview * ObjectCenter;

    // Z should be 0 by this time and the projective transform in w.
    // scale so w = 1  (these two should be in screen-space)
    vec2 newScreenPosition = screenPosition.xy / screenPosition.w;
    vec2 newObjectCenter   = screenObjectCenter.xy / screenObjectCenter.w;

    float d = distance(newScreenPosition, newObjectCenter);

    if (d < MinimumHeight && d > 0.0) {
        // Direction of this object, this really only makes sense in the context
        // of a line (eg: GL_LINES)
        vec2 towards = normalize(newScreenPosition - newObjectCenter);

        // Shift the center point then adjust the vertex position accordingly
        // Basically this converts: *--x--* into *--------x--------*
        newObjectCenter = newObjectCenter + towards * MinimumHeight;
        screenPosition.xy = newObjectCenter.xy * screenPosition.w;
    }

    gl_Position = screenPosition;
    DestinationColor = SourceColor;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that I didn't test the code, but it should illustrate the solution.

If you want to use shaders, add in another uniform vec4 that is the center position of your line.  Then you can do something similar to (note center could be precomputed on the CPU once):

```
uniform float MIN;   //Minimum size of blob on-screen
uniform vec4 center; //Center of the line / blob
...
vec4 screenPos = Projection * Modelview * Position;
vec4 center = Projection * Modelview * Position;

//Z should be 0 by this time and the projective transform in w.
//scale so w = 1  (these two should be in screen-space)
vec2 nScreenPos = screenPos.xy / screenPos.w;
vec2 nCenter = center.xy / center.w;

float d = distance(nScreenPos, nCenter);
if (d < MIN && d > 0)
{
    vec2 towards = normalize(nScreenPos - nCenter);
    nCenter = nCenter + towards * MIN;

    screenPos.xy = nCenter.xy * screenPos.w;
}

gl_Position = screenPos;
```

Find where on the screen the vertex would be drawn, then from the center of the blob stretch it if needed to ensure a minimum size.

This example is for round objects.  For corners, you could make `MIN` an attribute so the distance from the center varies on a per-vertex basis.

If you just want something more box-like, check that the minimum distance of the x and y coordinates separately.

On the CPU, you could compute the coordinates in screen-space and scale accordingly before submitting to the GPU.

Comment: Great, I'll give this is a try and report back.

Comment: Rereading the question, you may want to use small thin boxes (GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP) instead of lines so the vertex shader can stretch the height of the box.

Comment: I am currently using GL_LINES with and setting glLineWidth().  I know using GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP is preferred for many reasons but I was getting away with GL_LINES okay for now so I thought I would stick with it.  Is it not possible to use GL_LINES for this?  or just more difficult?

Comment: Hm, I have implemented your suggestion and a few other variants to boot, but the end result is not changed.  Actually it seems the vertex shader is doing nothing at all.  Just as proof the shader is active I'm setting DestinationColor to black (which works).

Comment: Aha, the shader is working a bit now.  Am going to rewrite this using GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP as you suggested.  I'm realizing that even if I get the shader working I won't be able to control both the minimum width and height of the line.  Afaict it isn't possible to alter the width of GL_LINES in a shader.

Comment: GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP would allow you to do the thicker lines in the shader as you just mentioned (a line being a continuous row of pixels).  To keep the line logic in your code, nothing precludes you from doing what a geometry-shader would do on the CPU and generate line data and have another piece of code generate the triangle strips.  Sorry if it is a sub-ideal set of solutions.

Comment: Finally got it working, thank you for the great tips mifortin.  In the end I kept the GL_LINES approach and creating an ObjectCenter attribute, rather than a uniform.  I find this solution works well with my scene by setting MinimumHeight to something around 0.005f, ymmv.